# mac/xcode setting up a specific UUID for Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I've been playing with the Bluetooh sample from the Xcode RFCOMM_SPP which is what would do the job for me so I modified it but the discover devices does not pick a few simpler SPP devices(like a GPS)

I had a similar issue when doing the Android version and after digging I found out if I set up a proper UUID manually I'm on easy street and that got me rolling there really cool

Now back to the MAC I'm trying to see if the same process can be applied I see they have this IOBluetoothSDPUUID which picks a pre-cooked UUID, my guess is that if I do there what I did in Android I'd be able to see and interface with the GPS.

Is it possible to set a UUID manually like adding it to the h files? Or is it blocked for "Made for Apple" devices like in the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Are you programming for the MAC or iOS devices (iphone / ipad )
Bluetooth SPP profile is not supported (publicly) on iOS devices. 
see this http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647?viewlocale=en_US

So if you want to do something custom on these devices using non public interfaces, the only way is joining the MFi program